# Yum Returns Errors when using

Tags: centos, yum, repository

When I try to use Yum (e.g. `# yum update`) I get an error and it prevents me from using Yum. Any help on this would be really cool!

This is the error that I get when I try to run a Yum command:

```
# yum update
Setting up Update Process
Setting up repositories
not using ftp, http[s], or file for repos, skipping - 4 is not a valid release or hasnt been released yet
Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: update
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: update
```

Here is the content of the `CentOS-Base.repo` file:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-centos4
protect=1

#released updates 
[update]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-centos4
protect=1 

#packages used/produced in the build but not released
[addons]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Addons
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=addons
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/addons/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-centos4
protect=0 

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-centos4
protect=0 

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-centos4
protect=0 

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=contrib
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-centos4
protect=0
```

Thanks in Advance!
Max Kulik

Comment: Can you share your `/etc/yum.repo.d/*` contents? It looks like you've got a typo in one of your .repo files or in your `/etc/yum.conf` file.

Comment: @slm: He damaged his configuration during [an earlier escapade](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82558/9785).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - thanks for saving me wasting my time on this. Do a re-install, would be my advice now. There isn't any value in us helping here, looks like your installation is corrupt.

Comment: @slm: This is a brand new install of CentOS and this is the 3rd time I have done a re-install I can guarantee that this is not a corrupt install. I will post the contents of `/etc/yum.repo.d/*` in the original post.

Comment: @slm: I just added the content of the `CentOS-Base.repo` file.

Comment: @slm, I still have the backup of the original `CentOS-Base.repo` file.

Comment: Instead of posting your repo file, what's the output of `yum repolist -v`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Open `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` in an editor
2. Comment out the "mirrorlist" entries.
3. Uncomment the "baseurl" entries and change them to

   ```
   http://vault.centos.org/4.9/os/$basearch
   ```

Or better, stop using unsupported OSes.

Answer (score 0):

Please let us know the .repo files inside your /etc/yum.repos.d/

try

> grep -iRl update /etc/yum.repos.d/

And find the instances of update inside the .repo file. probably you need to put

> enable=0

For the repo file section of "update"

Otherwise, try opening each and every .repo file you have inside the  /etc/yum.repos.d/ and check for repo section "update" and if you can spot anything, try disabling it by putting 0 to enable line.

Let us know if that worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Same issue,

```
#rpm -q centos-release
centos-release-4-4.3
```

Try to change your /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo 
by this: http://vault.centos.org/4.8/CentOS-Base.repo

It work for me.